# Find the solution of $y''+4y'+5y=0$ that satisfies the initial condition $ϕ(0)=1$ and $ϕ'(0)=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the following differential equation that satisfies the initial condition $ϕ(0)=1$ and $ϕ'(0)=0$:
$$y''+4y'+5y=0$$

After solving the problem I found that the solution to be $$ϕ(x) = c_1e^{-2x}(\cos(2x) - i\sin(2x)) + c_2 e^{-2x}(\cos(2x) + i\sin(2x))$$

Moving on from this step to find the solution satisfying the given initial condition is a nightmare because I have to deal with $i$. Anyone know an easier way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ϕ(0)=1\Rightarrow  c_1 + c_2 =1$$
$$ϕ'(x)=-2c_1e^{-2x}(\cos(2x) - i\sin(2x)) -2 c_2 e^{-2x}(\cos(2x) + i\sin(2x))+ c_1e^{-2x}(-2\sin(2x)-2i\cos(2x)) + c_2 e^{-2x}(-2\sin(2x) + 2i\cos(2x))$$
$$ϕ'(0)=0\Rightarrow -2c_1-2 c_2 -2ic_1+2ic_2=0 \Rightarrow -c_1- c_2 -ic_1+ic_2=0\Rightarrow -ic_1+ic_2=1\Rightarrow c_1-c_2=i$$
Finally :
$c_1=\frac{1+i}2$ and $c_2=\frac{1-i}2$

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution of form $y = e^{\lambda x}$, I got
$y(x) = c_1 e^{-2x} \sin(x) + c_2 e^{-2x} \cos(x)$ instead since you can rearrange the terms and absorb the $i$ into $c$.

If you rearrange your solution,
$c_1 e^{-2x}(\cos(2x) - i\sin(2x)) + c_2 e^{-2x}(\cos(2x) + i \sin(2x)) = e^{-2x}(c_1 \cos(2x) + c_2 \cos(2x)) + e^{-2x}((-i c_1 sin(2x) + ic_2 \sin(2x))  = e^{-2x}(c_1 + c_2) \cos(2x) + e^{-2x}(-i c_1 + ic_2) \sin(2x) $

Now you can rename $c_1 := (c_1 + c_2)$ and $c_2 := (-i c_1 + ic_2)$.

Solving the characteristic equation, we obtain $\lambda = -2 \pm i$. Thus
$$y(x) = c_1 e^{(-2+i)x} + c_2 e^{-(2+i)x}$$
Using Euler formular $e^{a + ib} = e^a \cos(b) + ie^a \sin(b)$ to obtain the reduced form.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $r^2+4r+5=0$ and upon solving this I got the answer mentioned above.

Comment: Symbolab.com gives me the answer $\quad y=e^{-2x}\left(c_1\cos \left(x\right)+c_2\sin \left(x\right)\right)$ Do you know why? What happened to the $2$ in $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/y''%2B4y'%2B5y%3D0

Comment: You can leave the 2 inside of $\sin$ and $\cos$ since it is equivalent. However, if you want to get rid of it quickly then you can use:
$e{a + ib} = e^a \cos(b) + ie^a \sin(b)$ where $a + ib$ corresponds $-2 \pm i$.